# maximize non-convex composite function

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

I want to maximize a composite function over a convex set
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\mathbf{p}}{\text{maximize}}
& & f(\mathbf{p})-g(\mathbf{p})\\
& \text{subject to}
& & \mathbf{p}^T\mathbf{C}_{m}\mathbf{p}\leq\beta_{m}, \; \forall m.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{p})=\log\sum_{k=1}^{N}\exp\Big[-\sum_{i}\log\Big(1+a_{i}\mathbf{p}^{T}\mathbf{A}_{k}\mathbf{p}\Big)\Big]\\
g(\mathbf{p})=\log\sum_{k=1}^{N}\exp\Big[-\sum_{i}\log\Big(1+a_{i}\mathbf{p}^{T}\mathbf{B}_{k}\mathbf{p}\Big)\Big].
\end{align}
All $\mathbf{A}_k, \mathbf{B}_k$ and $\mathbf{C}_m$ are positive semi-definite matrices; $a_i>0,b_i>0$ for all $i$. The main challenge of this problem is that $\mathbf{p}^{T}\mathbf{A}_{k}\mathbf{p}$ is a convex function, $\log(1+x)$ is a concave function and $\log\sum_{k=1}^{N}\exp(x_k)$ is a convex function. Clearly, both $f(\mathbf{p})$ and $g(\mathbf{p})$ are non-convex. How to maximize an objective function like this? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: have you already tried projected gradient and d.c. programming (the latter will require some work because your functions are purely nonconvex, but may be broken up in a way that enables d.c.)..

Comment: Hi, Survit. I had tried a lot of method to solve it. The first is something like SDP, by introducing a matrix $Q=pp^T$ the objective function can be transformed into a d.c. function, and then I relaxed the rank one constraint and solve it using CCCP. This method works well in practice but in theory it is not a global optimization method. I also tried to reformulate the objective function as (f(p)+k*p'*p)-(g(p)+k*p'*p). I can find a relative small k such that the objective function is a d.c. function, However, this method works really bad because k is still too large.

Comment: "not a global optimization method..." --- in general it'll be NP-Hard to get a global optimization here, and anything that'll be practical will be not global, so I don't see why you would not use the SDP based formulation (neglecting the rank constraint, or if you wish you can add a trace-norm constraint to encourage the system to have low rank solution)...

Comment: Yeah, this is in general a NP-hard problem, so I hope I can find a branch-and-bound based algorithm. The general QCQP can be solved globally by using the reformulation-and-linearization technique (RLT) and maximizing a d.c. function over a convex set can also be solved globally. However, it seems very difficult to combine them together....

Comment: I guess your use of the word "solve" is different from mine (by "solve" I mean: guaranteed polynomial time solve, not just a heuristic).
$$\phantom{a}$$
However, I don't have expertise in branch-and-bound style global optimization, so I'll leave it to someone else to answer. For approximate solutions you could still try SQP.

Comment: No guarantees AT ALL. Nevertheless, I was invited here to comment, so here goes. You could try using YALMIP with its own BMIBNB branch and bound global optimizer. To succeed, you'll need a good MILP solver (e.g, CPLEX, GUROBI, or maybe SCIP) and a good upper (local nonlinear) solver, such as KNITRO or SNOPT, or maybe IPOPT or FMINCON, which are called by BMIBNB to solve subproblems. Then maybe you can succeed. What is the dimension of p?  Do you have good starting values?  All the log and exp stuff is probably not helping matters.

Comment: You could also give BARON a whirl.  it can most easily be accessed via YALMIP, if you have the MATBAR converter installed under MATLAB.  I wouldn't invest a great deal of hope in its success though, unless your dimensions are small.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Actually I prefer to find a tight concave relaxation bound by myself, and then solve a sequence of convex optimization problems to approach the optimal value. I think these commercial global optimization solvers cannot solve my problem because they don't know how to exploit the structure of my problem. Moreover, based on my knowledge, only when the objective function and constraints are factorable, there exist general branch-and-bound algorithm.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how good BMIBNB"s relaxations are going to be - that is all done automatically. If the relaxations work out well, and are solved efficiently by the MILP solver, and the upper solver can find decent local optima, then the overall global optimization has a chance of working.

Comment: How did things go? Do you have an update?

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your attention on this problem. Finally I obtain a stationary point of this problem by the majorize-maximization algorithm. It works well in practice.

Comment: I think the global optimization algorithm for such a problem is too difficult....I designed a branch-and-bound based algorithm for this problem, but it works very bad in practice because the domain of f(p)-g(p) makes it very difficult to obtain a tight concave upper bound, see another post for details: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/244280/deriving-concave-upper-bounds-of-a-domain-constrained-nonconvex-function-over-a